# wait to promises inside for loop to end. Angular 7 / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await

I'm working with Angular 7 and I have a function that have a promise and save the result in an array like this:

```
appendImage(item){

this.imageCompress.compressFile(item, 50, 50).then(
  result => {
    this.compressedImages.push(result);
    return this.compressedImages;
  });
```

}

And I'm calling this function/promise from another function that have a for loop:

```
async compressFiles() {

if(this.elementsSelected.length > 0){
 for(let i = 0; i < this.elementsSelected.length; i++){
   let actual = this.elementsSelected[i].src;
   let res = await this.appendImage(actual);
   console.log(res);
 }

  return this.compressedImages;

}else{
  console.warn("No Images Selected");
}
```

}

And I need to return the array when all promise calls ends. When I print the array from the `appendImage()` function, I get the array just like I wanted it, but doing the `console.log(res)` I get `undefined`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly await your function, you need to return the promise.

```
appendImage(item){

this.imageCompress.compressFile(item, 50, 50).then(
  result => {
    this.compressedImages.push(result);
    return this.compressedImages;
  });
}
```

should be

```
appendImage(item){
// this is a promise, and you need to return it, in order to use await
return this.imageCompress.compressFile(item, 50, 50).then(
  result => {
    this.compressedImages.push(result);
    return this.compressedImages;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning from appendImage.

Try the below using an async function.

```
async appendImage(item) {
    const result = await this.imageCompress.compressFile(item, 50, 50);
    this.compressedImages.push(result);
    return this.compressedImages;
}
```